# Wordpress Essential Addons for Elementor not displaying styles

Tags: wordpress, ssl, elementor

I’m having problems with the plugin in one of the webs where I use it. The EA Elements are displayed but without style. Could it be a problem with the SSL? Here is an example, where the team members block is not styled:
https://www.ub.edu/comitedeseguretatisalut/composicio-cssub/

I read some related problems and tried some ideas but nothing worked. I deleted and reinstalled the plugin, I gave 777 permissions to the folder plugin, I deleted the cache… but nothing seems to work. Any idea or link to a topic where I could find a solution?

Note: It’s an institutional web, so the SSL was installed by other department and I can’t access the hosting configuration. Also, we have other web with SSL certificate where the plugin is working correctly.

Thank you very much for your help

https://www.ub.edu/comitedeseguretatisalut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your page and it has 6 `HTTP 403` errors. So it is clear that you have a permissions error.

[image]

What you can do is to choose `Internal Embedding` in Elementor Settings

[image]

This option will force all css styling `inline`.

If you don't want to use the internal embedding option, `777` folder permission could be the reason why your webserver is returning 403 errors. Try setting the folder permission to `755` and files to `644`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I checked the permissions, and it did not work, but changing the CSS Print Method did solve the problem.

Thanks again!

Comment: Happy to help! Please consider accepting this or any other answer that works for you.